# Catch exception during DataGrid editing?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am replicating a GUI version of the 'touch' command, for a user at work.

I have a WPF `DataGrid` that I am binding to a `List<FileInfo>` object.

When the user changes the CreationTime (for example) on a file, the binding automatically updates the file, and all is good.

Until you try to change a file that you do not have permission to change.  The databinding throws the exception to the output window, but I want to catch the exception and update the status bar message to say that it failed.

At the moment I am achieving this by catching the `CellEditEnding` event, and manually applying the change again, just to catch the exception in code.  This is not a problem, but I would like to know how to do this without attempting to change the date twice?

Comment: I really would like to catch the WPF exception, and handle that.  I don't know why the title was changed, the title does not match my question.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [`BeginningEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.beginningedit.aspx) event to ensure the file is accessible, and set the `Cancel` property of the passed [`DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridbeginningediteventargs.aspx) to `true` if the file is inaccessible.

To determine if you have write access to a certain path, use this:

```
using System.Security.Permissions;

...
public void dataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
{
    FileIOPermission permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, path);
    try
    {
        permission.Demand();            
    }
    catch
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: _Shazam_. I feel like such a dummy.  Didn't even occur to me to use that to check.  Thanks.

Comment: And I walk face first into the fact that there is no way to check if I have write access, without attempting to write.

Comment: @batGnat check my update. Don't forget to [vote and accept answers](http://i.imgur.com/fhbx269.png?1).